# Sitecore Experience Profile getting Error

Tags: experience-analytics, experience-profile

I am getting the following error in the logs when trying to load Experience Profile in `Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 170614)`:

```
7216 16:28:52 ERROR Key 'Internet Banking' does not exist in this pattern space
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Key 'Internet Banking' does not exist in this pattern space
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Patterns.PatternSpace.GetKeyIndex(String key)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Patterns.PercentagePatternMapper.GetPoints(PatternSpace space, IProfileData values)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Patterns.PatternSpace.CreatePattern(IProfileData profile)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`3.<CombineSelectors>b__0(TSource x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfilePatternMatch.Processors.PopulateProfilePatternMatchesWithXdbData.CalculateGravityForAllPatterns(ProfileItem profileContainingPatterns, Pattern referencePattern, Dictionary`2& patternsWithCalculatedGravityShare)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfilePatternMatch.Processors.PopulateProfilePatternMatchesWithXdbData.Process(ReportProcessorArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.PipelineViewProvider.GenerateContactView(ViewParameters viewParameters)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfileInfo.Processors.FindBestPatternMatchAndApplyToProfileInfo.ApplyPatternToOneProfile(ReportProcessorArgs args, DataRow profileRow)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.Contact.ProfileInfo.Processors.FindBestPatternMatchAndApplyToProfileInfo.ApplyPatternsToResultTable(ReportProcessorArgs args, DataTable resultTable)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Reporting.PipelineViewProvider.GenerateContactView(ViewParameters viewParameters)
   at Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.IntelController.Get(ViewParameters viewParams, Guid contactId, String viewId, String id)
```

The screenshot of the experience profile:

[image]

I already had a look at my profile key and I can see that `'Internet Banking'` 
Already exists as below:

[image]

I have already tried rebuilding link database and deploying marketing definitions options from control panel but no luck. Has anyone experience similar issue?

Comment: That's a known issue. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/631685 . Best contact with Sitecore Support

Comment: And maybe this article can help you: https://sitecorejourney.nileshthakkar.in/2015/10/are-you-getting-key-does-not-exist-in.html

Comment: @MarekMusielak Already had a look at that article. Unfortunately not able to resolve the issue. Also raised the issue with Sitecore Support, let's see what they come back with.